# how to fit the .exe into the user control using Active X control

Tags: c#, .net

I have created user control using Active X control in C# windows form. i want to add the another .exe in this control.
Ex: i create a login form when i login that time the another .exe open.
I want to fit this .exe in the user control.

Comment: I'm confused - what is it that you want to do? You want to put a binary file in an ActiveX control?

Comment: what kind of problems you get if you put both controls into same window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always include anything as "embedded resource" in your project.
But if you want to start the "exe" it depends whether the exe is itself an assembly (.NET) or not...
With a .NET exe you could launch it from memory...
With a non-.NET (=native) exe you need to write it to some storage and then start it from there...